# setting value to different cards in a deck of cards

Tags: java, arrays

Yes this is for a homework assignment but i am trying to learn how to code more object oriented. I need to have a different value for each card so that way when i run the compareTo method I am able to compare not only the number value of the card but also the suit ranking of the card. So as an example the ACE would have the value of 0, 13, 26, and 39. I have created a card class and everything is working when I run it through the deckOfCard class. I am just trying to write to Card method better so there is not so much code. I know there has to be a better way of doing it instead of have a bunch on nested if/else statements. Here is my Card class. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
public class Card{
private int number;
private String suit;
private char value;
private final int MAX_CARDS = 52;

/**
method: Card(int number)
Purpose: (Constructor)Creates a new Card based on the number

@1param   number of card to assign suit and value
@return  
*/
public Card(int number)
{
  //Assigning Values to the card
  if(number == 0 || number == 13 || number == 26 || number == 39)
  {
     value = 'A';
  }
  else if(number == 10 || number == 23 || number == 36 || number == 49)
  {
     value = 'J'; 
  }
  else if(number == 11 || number == 24 || number == 37 || number == 50)
  {
     value = 'Q';
  }
  else if(number == 12 || number == 25 || number == 38 || number == 51)
  {
     value = 'K';
  }
  else if(number == 1 || number == 14 || number == 27 || number == 40)
  {
     value = '2';
  }
  else if(number == 2 || number == 15 || number == 28 || number == 41)
  {
     value = '3';
  }
  else if(number == 3 || number == 16 || number == 29 || number == 42)
  {
     value = '4';
  }
  else if(number == 4 || number == 17 || number == 30 || number == 43)
  {
     value = '5';
  }
  else if(number == 5 || number == 18 || number == 31 || number == 44)
  {
     value = '6';
  }
  else if(number == 6|| number == 19 || number == 32 || number == 45)
  {
     value = '7';
  }
  else if(number == 7 || number == 20 || number == 33 || number == 46)
  {
     value = '8';
  }
  else if(number == 8 || number == 21 || number == 34 || number == 47)
  {
     value = '9';
  }
  else if(number == 9 || number == 22 || number == 35 || number == 48)
  {
     value = 'T';
  }
  //Assigning Suit
  // Hearts > Spades > Diamonds > Clubs
  if(number>=0 && number<=12)
  {
     suit = "Clubs";
  }
  else if(number>=13 && number<=25)
  {
     suit = "Diamonds";
  }
  else if(number>=26 && number<=38)
  {
     suit = "Spades";
  }
  else
  {
     suit = "Hearts";
  }

}   
/**
method: getValue()
Purpose: (Getter)returns value

@param   
@return  value
*/   
public char getValue()
{   

  return value;
}
/**
method: getNumber()
Purpose: (Getter)returns number

@param   
@return  number
*/   
public int getNumber()
{
  return number;
}                  

/**
method: getSuit(int number)
Purpose: returns suit based on number value

@param   number of card to assign suit
@return  suit
*/ 
public String getSuit()
{             

  return suit;            
}
public String toString()
{
  return value + " of " + suit;
}
/**
method: compareTo(Card aCard)
Purpose: Return an integer comparison of two cards

@param   aCard reference to the card being compared
@return  integer difference between two cards
*/
public int compareTo(Card aCard)
{
  int cardSuitValueA = -1;
  int cardSuitValueB = -1;
  int cardsPerSuit = 13;
  if(this.getNumber() % cardsPerSuit - aCard.getNumber() % cardsPerSuit !=     0)
  {
     return this.getNumber() % cardsPerSuit - aCard.getNumber() %  cardsPerSuit;
  }
  else
  {
     if (this.getSuit().equalsIgnoreCase("Hearts"))
     {
        cardSuitValueA = 3;
     }
     else if (this.getSuit().equalsIgnoreCase("Spades"))
     {
        cardSuitValueA = 2;
     }
     else if (this.getSuit().equalsIgnoreCase("Diamonds"))
     {
        cardSuitValueA = 1;
     }         
     else if (this.getSuit().equalsIgnoreCase("Clubs"))
     {
        cardSuitValueA = 0;
     }
     if (aCard.getSuit().equalsIgnoreCase("Hearts"))
     {
        cardSuitValueB = 3;
     }
     else if (aCard.getSuit().equalsIgnoreCase("Spades"))
     {
        cardSuitValueB = 2;
     }
     else if (aCard.getSuit().equalsIgnoreCase("Diamonds"))
     {
        cardSuitValueB = 1;
     }         
     else if (aCard.getSuit().equalsIgnoreCase("Clubs"))
     {
        cardSuitValueB = 0;
     }
     return cardSuitValueA - cardSuitValueB;
   }        
 }   

}
```

Comment: One thing that you should definitely consider is replacing the `String` with an `enum`. Using string variables for logic (comparisons) is generally a bad idea, as it makes the code a mess and is pretty inefficient as well. Not to mention that typos become hard to find, as they are still correct strings

Comment: Since you're asking for general advice, this question would be more suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i totally agrees after reading through some of the documents on enum i find it easier and much much cleaner with the coding. I just can't do that with this project and trying to figure the easier way.

Comment: Why can't you use enums?

Comment: honestly i am still trying to understand how i could implement them in this situation.

Comment: Actually I just realized that in your implementation the private variable `number` is never assigned a value, so it cannot work correctly. (This is fixed in @JornVernee's answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enum`s. This could for instance, significantly compact your `compareTo`:

```
public class Card implements Comparable<Card> {
    private final int number;
    private final Rank rank;
    private final Suit suit;

    private static final int CARDS_PER_SUIT = 13;

    private Card(Suit suit, Rank rank, int number) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Card(Suit suit, Rank rank) {
        this(suit, rank, suit.ordinal() * CARDS_PER_SUIT + rank.ordinal());
    }

    public Card(int number) {
        this(Suit.ofNumber(number), Rank.ofNumber(number), number);
    }

    //... Boilerplate methods

    private static final Comparator<Card> defaultComparator
        = Comparator.comparing(Card::getRank).thenComparing(Card::getSuit);

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card aCard) {
        return defaultComparator.compare(this, aCard);
    }

    public enum Suit {
        Clubs,
        Diamonds,
        Spades,
        Hearts;

        public static Suit ofNumber(int number) {
            return values()[number / CARDS_PER_SUIT];
        }
    }

    public enum Rank {
        Ace,
        Two,
        Three,
        Four,
        Five,
        Six,
        Seven,
        Eight,
        Nine,
        Ten,
        Jack,
        Queen,
        King;

        public static Rank ofNumber(int number) {
            return values()[number % CARDS_PER_SUIT];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, so I understand that with an 'enum' you you are creating your own special variable type. And from what you provided I see how you are able to do that. Now my question is with your 'suit.ordinal()' what is the 'oridinal' part of the statement. I have not seen that before.

Comment: never mind i just found the answer on the oracle website about what the ordinal() means.

Comment: @ChadHoye It is a method generated by the compiler. It is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal--). It basically returns the index of the enum value.

Comment: I tried running the code you provided and i get an error saying that it's an invalid method reference on the "Comparator<Card>"

Comment: @ChadHoye Did you add the `getRank` and `getCard` methods? (that is what I meant by "boilerplate methods", i.e. getters/setters/toString/etc.

Comment: I was wondering what that meant and now that i have put them in it works and i see how it is working. so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (i did only ranks, not suits, but you get the point, you can do the same with suits or just leave it like you have right now):

```java
private static Map<Integer, Character> map = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
static{
  map.put(0, 'A');
  map.put(10, 'J');
  map.put(11, 'Q');
  map.put(12, 'K');
  ...
}

public Card(int number){
  value = map.get(number%13);
}
```

This way your compareTo method can be greatly reduced aswell. You can also put those values in normal array instead of map if you are not comfortable with maps (index `0` will be `'A'`, index `10` will be `'J'` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the modulo operator to make it simpler

```
public Card(int number)
{
  //Assigning Values to the card
  if((number % 13) == 0)
  {
     value = 'A';
  }
  else if((number % 13) == 10)
  {
     value = 'J'; 
  }
  else if((number % 13) == 11)
  {
     value = 'Q';
  }
  else if((number % 13) == 12)
  {
     value = 'K';
  }
  else if((number % 13) == 1)
  {
     value = '2';
  }
```

or keep an array and use `(number % 13)` to index into it. `(number % 13)` is the remainder when you divide `number` by 13.

```
public Card(int number)
{
  //Assigning Values to the card
  char[] ranks = {'A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K' };
  value = ranks[number % 13];

  char[] suits = {'S', 'H', 'D', 'C' };
  suit = suits[number / 13];

}
```

Comment: i like that but i still would need the same about of if/else statements correct

Comment: couldn't you replace the if-else with a switch-case? (which would also mean you only perform the calculation only once)

Comment: i had talked to someone else about doing that but he had 52 switch statements which i though was ridiculous.

Comment: I like the array approach better, and yes, switch-case avoids multiple calculations.

Comment: i love the method you sent me that worked beautifully and is much simpler then what i originally had. I new there was something i could do to improve it. can i do the same sort of thing for the if/else statements that i have for the suits in the same constructor.

Comment: @ChadHoye for the suits it should be `number / 13` if I understand your code correctly (and you'd have a second array with the suits listed)

Comment: Just added suit calc - as UnholySheep says, index by `number/13`